# FindQt5.cmake in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have started to practice Qt and now working on a mp3 file player and in order to do that I have to use a library called QtMediaPlayer and QMultiMedia.

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Multimedia REQUIRED)

add_executable(MyMp3Player main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)


target_link_libraries(MyMp3Player Qt5::Multimedia)
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a **question**. Does the code work? If not, what error message have you got? Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] the question post accordingly.

Comment: Well the problem is I cant add the required ibraries and this is the error message that I get when I try to run it, I searched it on google and cant find anything about it

Comment: Please, incorporate those details into the **question post**. And do not forget to post **complete** error message.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your kind information I will do it as soon as possible